# How do I set up a view to filter on URL path?

Tags: 7, views

Can views show me all menu items with paths that match a particular pattern?

I have a documentation section which is mostly basic pages, but there's some views that belong here, too. I have set the views' paths to doc/some-view-name.

I would like to use a View to find all documentation pages (including pages created by Views) identified by the path doc/*

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to filter nodes by their path you will have to use [menu_link](http://drupal.org/project/menu_link). (i havent used it though).

As far as i know there is no simple way of displaying content of the menu related tables, which is what you would have to do to include the views in the result. Some discussion and a direction of coding is here : http://groups.drupal.org/node/22731 Unfortunately the module suggested there wouls help you neither - it is again just for nodes.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify how to filter nodes by their path? I've tried searching the Filter (and the Relationship bit) for "path", "url", "alias" and nothing useful comes up.

Comment: sorry, i didnt realize the path is only available as a field, not as a filter. improving answer ...